# Wrong vertical alignment of inline-block divs

Tags: html, css

I have some inline-block divs and I want them to appear in line, not one higher than another, like it is now.

Here it is the most important part of the webpage:

The HTML:

```
<div id="hand">
    <div class="card">Y += 1;<br></div>
    <div class="card">if ( Y == 6 &amp;&amp; X &lt; 2 &amp;&amp; X &gt; -2) {<br> Y *= -1;<br> X -= 5;<br> } </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#hand {
position: absolute;
display: block;
bottom: 0;
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.card {
text-align: left;
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
padding: 30px;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgb(200,200,200);
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 0 20px;
}
```

I've prepeared a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/su0cbwkr/3/) for you guys.

**EDIT**:

I noticed that the most bottom character of the top div is in the same height as the top most character of the bottom div. Maybe it's a text thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`display: inline-block` is vertically aligning your cards along the bottom (baseline) of the **text** within them, because the default ("initial value") for [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is *baseline*.

Add `vertical-align: top` to it's CSS and everything should line up nicely.

Comment: OP also does not need `position:relative` or `bottom:0` once the vertical-align is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

I added float to your cards class. And if you want to align it to centre then use `margin: auto;` for parent div.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
html, body {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#hand {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 400px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.card {
 text-align: left;
 bottom: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 150px;
 padding: 30px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgb(200,200,200);
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 0 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="hand">
  <div id="1" class="card 0">Y += 1;<br></div>
  <div id="0" class="card 1">if ( Y == 6 &amp;&amp; X &lt; 2 &amp;&amp; X &gt; -2) {<br> Y *= -1;<br> X -= 5;<br>} </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But they are supposed to be aligned in the middle

Comment: `float` is almost always a poor choice of solution these days, because it pulls the floated blocks out of the flow; and if you _are_ floating you can leave display as `block`. `inline-block` or a flex layout will do a better job.